# Prove that a product of $X_i$ is path connected, then each of $X_i$ is path connected.

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

I could find a bunch of Q&As on this website about the following proof:

> > For the finite product space, $X=X_1 \times X_2 \times X_3 \times ... X_n$,
> >
> > If each $X_i$ is path connected, then X is also path connected.

I am trying to prove the reverse:

> > For the finite product space, $X=X_1 \times X_2 \times X_3 \times ... X_n$,
> >
> > If X is path connected, then each of $X_i$ is path connected.

I could not find this answers in this website. 
I searched many textbooks as follows:

```
   James Munkres Topology, 2nd.

   Gamelin T.W., Greene R.E. Introduction to topology

   A. Lahiri A First Course in Algebraic Topology

   John McCleary A First Course in Topology

   Seymour Lipschutz Schaum’s Outline of General Topology Schaum’s Outlines  

   Stephen Willard General Topology
```

Only one of them, Gamelin T.W., Greene R.E. Introduction to topology (page95, Ex 4(e)), has this proof.

However, the solution says I need to refer to the Ex 9.3, page 90, but I cannot understand the solution of it, page 216.

It says as follows:

> > Prove that if X is path connected and $f:X \to Y$ is $\color{red}{a\,map}$, then f(X) is path connected.
> >
> > SOLUTION: If $p=f(x)$ and $q=f(y)$, and $\gamma$ is a path in X from p to q, then $f \circ \gamma $ is a path in f(X) from x to y.

First, I do not know the meaning of "$\color{red}{a\,map}$". Does this mean a continuous function?

Also, I guess something is wrong, since x and y are in X, and p and q are in f(X). The statement in the book is the reverse.

Finally, I appreciate if there is another version of easier proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes a map is often used for "continuous function".

He starts with $p,q \in f[X]$ so he writes them right away as $p= f(x)$ for some $x \in X$ and $q = f(y)$ for some $y \in X$. There is a path from $x$ to $y$ in $X$, so a continuous $\gamma: [0,1] \to X$ with $\gamma(0) = x$ and $\gamma(1)=y$.

Then $f \circ \gamma: [0,1] \to Y$ is continuous as a composition of continuous maps and $(f\circ \gamma)(0) = f(\gamma(0)) = f(x) = p$ and $(f \circ \gamma)(1) = f(\gamma(1))= f(y) = q$ so we have a path from $p$ to $q$, for any two points $p,q \in f[X]$, i.e. $f[X]$ is path-connected.

It cannot be made easier than this, IMHO.

Then apply this fact to the continuous projections for the original statement.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation. I can perfectly understand it!!

Comment: @acubens555 It's just restating what you quoted, really. but glad to help..

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $X$ is path connected. Let $x_i,y_i\in X_i$. Consider $x_j,y_j\in X_j, i\neq j$, you have a continuous path $c(t)$ between $(x_1,...,x_n)$ and $(y_1,...,y_n)$, the composition $p_i\circ c$ where $p_i:X\rightarrow X_i$ is the canonical projection is a continuous path between $x_i$ and $y_i$.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation. I wish I could choose both of two answers, but it is impossible. I am sorry that I could not choose yours.